# Insert fabric image onto canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I setup a canvas with id `edit-canvas`. At first, I upload a background image and render it on that canvas. Now I want to import additional images on which I can manipulate (zoom, drag...) using Fabricjs. I have functions like these so as to import images every time I click on them before further manipulating:

```
function insertImage(src){
    var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('edit-canvas');
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(url,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
    fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function (img) {
        var oImg = img.set({left:0,top: 0});
        canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
        canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
    });
}

$('#sticker-tool .sticker-selection img').click(function(){
                    insertImage(this.src);
});
```

When I click on an image, my drawn background image is completely cleared. How can I fix it? My code now is also unable to render multiple imported images? How can I keep uploaded background image and control imported images as if they are layers on background?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a new fabric instance and setting the background each time you call `insertImage`?

`var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('edit-canvas');
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(url,canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));`

call it once and then only add new images with the `insertImage` function.